# base64enc unable to install

Tags: r, installation

I tried installing `base64enc`:

```
install.packages('base64enc',,'http://www.rforge.net/base64enc')
```

I am getting this error:

> Warning: unable to access index for repository http://www.rforge.net/base64enc/bin/windows/contrib/3.1
>       Warning message:
>       package ‘base64enc’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)

Comment: This package is available on CRAN. Simply try `install.packages('base64enc')`.

Comment: install.packages('base64enc')
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://ftp.ussg.iu.edu/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.1
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.1
Warning message:
package ‘base64enc’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)

Comment: Try to change the mirror.